# How to debug MySQL/Doctrine2 Queries?

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, doctrine-orm

I am using MySQL with Zend Framework & Doctrine 2. I think even if you don't use Doctrine 2, you will be familiar with errors like

> `SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ASC' at line 1`

The problem is that I don't see the full query. Without an ORM framework, I could probably echo the sql easily, but with a framework, how can I find out what SQL its trying to execute? I narrowed the error down to

```
$progress = $task->getProgress();
```

`$progress` is declared

```
// Application\Models\Task
/**
 * @OneToMany(targetEntity="TaskProgress", mappedBy="task")
 * @OrderBy({"seq" = "ASC"})
 */
protected $progress;
```

In MySQL, the task class looks like

```
CREATE TABLE `tasks` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `owner_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `assigned_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `list_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  `seq` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `tasks_owner_id_idx` (`owner_id`),
  KEY `tasks_assigned_id_idx` (`assigned_id`),
  KEY `tasks_list_id_idx` (`list_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `tasks_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`owner_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `tasks_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`assigned_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `tasks_ibfk_3` FOREIGN KEY (`list_id`) REFERENCES `lists` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1$$
```

Comment: If you have a Doctrine query object, which is unclear in the code you have posted, you can run `$query->getSqlQuery()` to see the SQL.  Find your query object in your code and output it to see whats going on.  Alternately you can turn on query logging in SQL to see what it is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

how about using [mysql general query log](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/query-log.html)?

> The general query log is a general record of what mysqld is doing. The server writes information to this log when clients connect or disconnect, and it logs each SQL statement received from clients. The general query log can be very useful when you suspect an error in a client and want to know exactly what the client sent to mysqld.

Comment: I can't enable it in CLI with `--general_log=1 --general_log_file="..."` but I managed to in MySQL with `SET global general_log = 'ON'`

Answer (score 96):

Most simple solution for debugging queries in Doctrine 2:

```
$em->getConnection()
  ->getConfiguration()
  ->setSQLLogger(new \Doctrine\DBAL\Logging\EchoSQLLogger())
;
```

Comment: This way didnt work for me, I had to call it like this: $em->getConnection()->getConfiguration()->setSQLLogger(
        new Doctrine\DBAL\Logging\EchoSQLLogger());

Comment: This is by far the best answer here.

Comment: In most cases it's ok, but in certain case it's not sufficient... when you have problems with your parameters... mysql General query log give the exact SQL query which will be executed with the parameters replaced.

Comment: No way to set it via YAML configuration, is it? Look like [*DoctrineBundle* does not supports anything other than `logging`](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineBundle/blob/1.12.x/Resources/config/schema/doctrine-1.0.xsd#L37). – I tried to tag the default logger into *services.yaml*, with `Doctrine\DBAL\Logging\EchoSQLLogger: '@doctrine.dbal.logger'` but doesn't seem to sort any effect.

Comment: I was doing it the other way around – Adding `doctrine.dbal.logger`(newline)`class: Doctrine\DBAL\Logging\EchoSQLLogger` inside `services.yaml` made it work!

Comment: As of today (22 Sep 2021), the EchoSqlLogger class is deprecated. You can of course easily move the code to your project and continue using the logger.

Answer (score 13):

You have to use a DBAL SQLLogger. You can use the basic native SQL Logger **\Doctrine\DBAL\Logging\EchoSQLLogger**, or you can implement yours with an interface of **Doctrine\DBAL\Logging\SQLLogger**.

For the basic logger you must attach the SQL Logger to the EntityManager. So, in your Doctrine bootstrap file use:

```
$config = new Doctrine\ORM\Configuration ();
// ... config stuff
$config->setSQLLogger(new \Doctrine\DBAL\Logging\EchoSQLLogger());
$connectionParams = array(
        'dbname' => 'example',
        'user' => 'example',
        'password' => 'example',
        'host' => 'localhost',
        'driver' => 'pdo_mysql');
//make the connection through an Array of params ($connectionParams)
$em = EntityManager::create($connectionParams, $config);
```

Note that we create our EntityManager from the **$connectionParams** array.

**Important:**. If you use a DBAL Connection for creating your EntityManager, you have to attach it in both, the DBAL Connection and the ORM EntityManager. For example, in Zend Framework,

You do this:

```
$config = new Doctrine\ORM\Configuration ();
// ...config stuff
// LOGGER
$config->setSQLLogger(new \Doctrine\DBAL\Logging\EchoSQLLogger());

// make the connection through DBAL (DriverManager::getConnection)
// note that we attach $config in $connApp(DBAL) and $emApp(ORM)
$connApp = DriverManager::getConnection($connectionParams, $config);
$emApp = EntityManager::create($connApp, $config);
Zend_Registry::set('emApp', $emApp);
Zend_Registry::set('connApp', $connApp);
```

Answer (score 5):

Use Doctrine2 profiler + Firebug

https://github.com/mridgway/ZendX_Doctrine2/

Answer (score 2):

Try to use Mysql proxy between you and the MySQL server (http://forge.mysql.com/wiki/MySQL_Proxy). Then you can configure this proxy to log all requests.

http://mysql.stu.edu.tw/tech-resources/articles/proxy-gettingstarted.html

Comment: Link broken, http://mysql.stu.edu.tw/tech-resources/articles/proxy-gettingstarted.html

Comment: Thanks, fixed. You could try an edit instead, it would be reviewed if you do not have enough reputations for a direct edit.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a blog article on this topic with some instructions for setting up profiling Doctrine 2 in Zend Framework

ZFDebug is already very nice, and there is a Doctrine 2 plugin for it

http://labs.ultravioletdesign.co.uk/profiling-doctrine-2-with-zend-framework/

Answer (score 2):

If your developing in ZF2 you can either use the solution above posted by **beberlei**, though this does echo it out to your display which is not exactly best practice but useful.

```
$em->getConnection()
  ->getConfiguration()
  ->setSQLLogger(new \Doctrine\DBAL\Logging\EchoSQLLogger())
;
```

or you could use [ZendDeveloperTools](https://github.com/zendframework/ZendDeveloperTools) which displays the execute query on the toolbar.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should use a **Zend_Db_Profile** in your **[development]** environment.

This will log your queries with runtime and other informations.

If you have an error log that logs your exceptions, then everything can be found in your log files.

See this link: [Zend Enable SQL Query logging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8114988/zend-enable-sql-query-logging)

Also see this Zend Framework Helper: https://github.com/jokkedk/ZFDebug