# Doctrine 2 - getSQL from $em->find()

Tags: php, doctrine, doctrine-orm

Could someone tell me, how to take pure SQL from `$em->find()` method?

Comment: Why do you need this? For debug purpose? If that is what you want to do, I would suggest the mysql query log.

Comment: @Max Yeah, but what, if I don't use MySql :>?

Comment: You should, it has a query log :>

Comment: @Max Yeah, but I think that PostgreSQL is better than MySQL (although I'm using MySQL, for now). Nevertheless, I need versatile solution for this problem.

Comment: @Max And... I want to check SQL Queries from the browser.

Comment: You could´ve made it way easier if you´d include those facts in your original question. Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4570608/how-to-debug-mysql-doctrine2-queries (2. answer re. EchoSQLLogger).

Answer (score 4):

Your question is unclear.

- If you mean "is it possible to find objects with raw SQL", then check the [Native SQL section in the Doctrine 2 documentation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/native-sql.html);
- If you mean "is it possible to see the SQL generated by a Doctrine query", then configure a SQL logger, as outlined in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4585421/759866).

Comment: I know, that it's possible to get raw SQL with `getSQL()` method from `$entity_manager->createQuery()`. I'm asking, if it's possible to get raw SQL from `$entity_manager->find()` method.

Comment: The SQL logger gives you the output of *all* queries generated by Doctrine 2. If you just need this information for debugging, that will do the job.

Comment: Could You give me any instructions, about how to use it, please?

Comment: `$em->getConfiguration()->setSQLLogger(new \Doctrine\DBAL\Logging\EchoSQLLogger);`

Comment: Ok, and how can I get those SQL queries from this logger?

Comment: They should be echoed in the page directly!

Comment: Yeah, but with what method / class?

Comment: Call this method on your `EntityManager`, then when you call `find()` or execute any other Doctrine query, the SQL query should be echoed in the page directly.