# persist() and flush() inside loop - Doctrine

Tags: php, collections, orm, doctrine, data-access-layer

I want to know how many times the ff: codes will make a roundway trip to the database.

```
foreach ($recipients as $recipient) {
    $received_email = new ReceivedEmail();
    $received_email->setRecipient($recipient);
    $received_email->setEmail($email);

    $entityManager->persist($received_email);
    $entityManager->flush(); 
}
```

`$recipients` is an array of User objects with One-to-Many relationship with ReceivedEmail

`$email` is an object with One-to-Many relationship with ReceivedEmail.

If for instance `$recipients` has five entities, does the loop generates a total of five trips to database? Or only one?

Is the above example the most optimized way to insert new ReceivedEmail records?

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There will be generated one INSERT statement for each persist.

What is more, you can just display yours SQL statements for debug, just configure Doctrine for logging:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/4585421/1815881

In your case:

```
$entityManager->getConfiguration()->
                setSQLLogger(new \Doctrine\DBAL\Logging\EchoSQLLogger());
```

For many inserts you should consider the **batch prcessing**:

- https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/batch-processing.html

Hope I have revealed the problem.

Comment: Thanks. I guess I would just use nativeSQL for inserting multiple ReceivedEmail  in my example so as to minimize the number of database trips

Comment: @Athlan, you did not specify what exactly `flush` does.

Comment: An `insert` statement for each `persist` does not mean that it will create a new record for each `persist`. It will check to see if the object being `persisted` already exists, meaning that you have to create a new object for each `persist`.